# Python replace comma separated words in list to dictionary value if existed in dictionary key

Tags: python

I would like to replace words to corresponding dictionary key:value if exist. For example, I have a comma separated list

```
unfiltered = ['Cat,Dog,Cow','','Horse,Whale','Fish,Giant Elephant']
```

and would like to change 'Whale' to 'Big Whale' and 'Fish' to 'Jellyfish' like this dictionary:

```
word_to_change = {'Whale': 'Big Whale', 'Fish': 'Jellyfish'}
```

to make the result like this:

```
['Cat,Dog,Cow','','Horse,Big Whale','Jellyfish,Giant Elephant']
```

I could combine all the elements in 'unfiltered' list and filtered with dictionary value:

```
unfiltered_combine = ['Cat','Dog','Cow','','Horse','Whale','Fish','Giant Elephant']

[x if x not in word_to_change else word_to_change[x] for x in lists]
```

Result when filtering combined words:

```
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow', '', 'Horse', 'Big Whale', 'Jellyfish', 'Giant Elephant']
```

However, I want to keep the list 'unfiltered' without combining its elements. Is there any way to filter the 'unfiltered' list to 'word_to_change' dictionary key:value? I would sincerely appreciate if you could give some advice.

Comment: You can use .get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us the following comprehension:

```
unfiltered = ['Cat,Dog,Cow', '', 'Horse,Whale', 'Fish,Giant Elephant']
wtc = {'Whale': 'Big Whale', 'Fish': 'Jellyfish'}

result = [','.join(wtc.get(s, s) for s in e.split(',')) for e in unfiltered]
# ['Cat,Dog,Cow', '', 'Horse,Big Whale', 'Jellyfish,Giant Elephant']
```

This makes use of the [`dict.get(key, default)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method. You [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the list elements, apply the conversion and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the tokens back together.

Answer (score 0):

```
unfiltered = ['Cat,Dog,Cow','','Horse,Whale','Fish,Giant Elephant']
word_to_change = {'Whale': 'Big Whale', 'Fish': 'Jellyfish'}

for key, value in word_to_change.items():
    unfiltered = [w.replace(key, value) for w in unfiltered]
```

Output:

```
['Cat,Dog,Cow', '', 'Horse,Big Whale', 'Jellyfish,Giant Elephant']
```

Edited: only works properly if the new values are not in the initial list.

Comment: This will, however, overapply: e.g. 'Big Whale' -> 'Big Big Whale'. It also does a single iteration for each entry in the dict which is unnecessary.